# Repeating a line in Python

Tags: python, printing, repeat

I've been trying to figure out how to repeat a simple "print" but to no avail. I would like to know what command I should be using and how the command is used. I don't have any code for this cause I got so angry with it that I deleted the file...

Comment: How about reading a [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/)? Also, it is not clear what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, but which tutorial should I be reading? I'm kinda new at this...

Comment: Well, for example the tutorial linked to in BlaXpirit's comment. Especially the sections 4.2-3 (`for` statement and `range()` function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming Python 2:

```
repeats = int(raw_input("How many repetitions? "))
for i in range(repeats):
    print "I will read a Python tutorial!"
```